# android example for Google Search API

Tags: android, api, search

Can anyone refer me to an example for Android application using results of Google Search API?
I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has discontinued its public search API, as far as I'm aware. Depending on your application, you could use the suggestions API instead, available at:

http://google.com/complete/search?q=query&output=toolbar